# How to determine Image Type based on Color ID

Tags: sql-server

I have one table and would like to populate the ImageType_page using COLORID for records with the same ID.

Conditions:

- If any of the Page# with the same ID has a COLORID = 1, SET ImageType_page = TIFF for all Page# within that same ID
- If any of the Page# with the same ID has a COLORID = 2, SET ImageType_page = TIFF-JPEG for all Page# within that same ID

Here is my table:

```
Page#     | ID  |   PageColor      |  COLORID   | ImageType_page   
AT000001  | 1   |   Black & White  |     1      | 
AT000002  | 1   |   Color          |     2      | 
AT000003  | 2   |   Color          |     2      | 
AT000004  | 2   |   Black & White  |     1      | 
AT000005  | 3   |   Black & White  |     1      | 
AT000006  | 3   |   Black & White  |     1      |
```

Results should be:

```
 Page#    |    ID   |   PageColor      |  COLORID   | ImageType_page

AT000001  | 1   |   Black & White  |     1      | TIFF-JPEG
AT000002  | 1   |   Color          |     2      | TIFF-JPEG
AT000003  | 2   |   Color          |     2      | TIFF-JPEG
AT000004  | 2   |   Black & White  |     1      | TIFF-JPEG
AT000005  | 3   |   Black & White  |     1      | TIFF
AT000006  | 3   |   Black & White  |     1      | TIFF
```

Here is some code I wrote that doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
update dbo.tblPage
set [IMAGE TYPE_page] = 'TIFF-JPEG'
Where [COLORID] = 2

update td
set [IMAGE TYPE_page] = (select [IMAGE TYPE_page] FROM tblPAGE td2 where td2.id = td.ID)
from tblPAGE td
where (COLORID = 1)
```

Comment: Sql Server or Mysql and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please show us the query you tried, and explain what problems you are having with it.

Comment: [`How to ask a question on Stackoverflow`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I suggest you read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This question is in a much better state, thanks for editing. Now nominated for reopening. However, I'd recommend one change - avoid the phrase "doesn't work" in absolutely all circumstances. Readers often say here that it is "the least helpful fault report possible"; say instead what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to get all the IDs that have ColorID = 2 and join to that in update:

```
with cte as
(
  select distinct id from tblPage where colorid = 2
)
update tbl
set imagetype = CASE WHEN cte.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'TIFF-JPEG' ELSE 'TIFF' END
from tblPage tbl
left join cte on cte.id = tbl.id
```

Alternatively you can group by ID and look for max ColorID:

```
with cte as
(
  select id, max(colorid) as maxcolorid
  from tblPage
  group by id
)
update tbl
set imagetype = CASE cte.maxcolorid WHEN 2 THEN 'TIFF-JPEG' ELSE 'TIFF' END
from tblPage tbl
inner join cte on cte.id = tbl.id
```